# Uncaught TypeError on the server but works on the client

Tags: meteor

When I run this:

```
  var vtop=Posts.findOne({},{sort: {created_at:-1},reactive:false}).created_at;
  console.log(vtop);
```

It comes up with an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'created_at' of undefined", but when I run `Posts.findOne({},{sort: {created_at:-1},reactive:false}).created_at;` on the web console it comes up with the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your subscriptions are complete before you call data.

In meteor data is sent on the wire, so when your javascript/html is sent down the browser hasn't yet been told to download the data from the server.

There are two ways round this:

If you've not yet reached the stage you're using subscriptions with your app you can use Deps.autorun

**Using Deps**

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    var subscribed = Session.equals("subscribed",true);
    if(!subscribed && Posts.find().count()) {
        Session.set("subscribed",true);

        var vtop = Posts.findOne({},{sort: {created_at:-1},reactive:false}).created_at;
        console.log(vtop)
    }
```

**OR wait for the subscription to finish**

*Server js*

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function() {
    return Posts.find();
}
```

*Client js*

```
Meteor.subscribe("posts",function() {
    var vtop = Posts.findOne({},{sort: {created_at:-1},reactive:false}).created_at;
    console.log(vtop)
});
```

If using the publish/subscribe you need to remove the `autopublish` package but if you do this you also need to publish your other Collections or the browser won't see them.

For more on how to use publish see the docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#publishandsubscribe

The parties example also uses publish and has a screencast : http://meteor.com/examples/parties

Answer (score 0):

I would put a breakpoint at that line of code and see what you have in your Posts collection at the moment when your JavaScript engine is about to run it. My guess is that your Posts collection is being loaded with documents *after* it comes across that line of code. The reason it works when you check with the web console is because at the point the documents have been loaded.